# How do I capture the selected column index in a TreeView in C#

Tags: c#, treeview, gtk

I am developing a C# api using Mono and Gtk and am having trouble trying to make my treeView cells editable. I found several code snippets on this, but the problem is that none of the provided solutions allow for ALL columns to be edited.

Here is my function

```
public void cellEdited (object o, Gtk.EditedArgs args)
    {
        TreePath path = new TreePath (args.Path);
        TreeIter iter;

        listStore.GetIter (out iter, path);
        int numberOfSelectedRow_ = path.Indices[0];
        listStore.SetValue (iter, COLUMN_NUMBER, args.NewText);
    }
```

The problem is that I cannot make out how to capture the column number of the selected cell.
I have read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352760/how-do-i-capture-the-selected-row-and-column-in-a-treeview-in-pygtk) saying that we should work with gtk.TreeView.get_path_at_pos but I don't really understand how exactly. Any code snippet would be really appreciated !!! Thank you all in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd the same issue but found a Solution (and for some other issues too.
1st we have to queue the Editing sender Object, because ther are different views for cancel an editin process. 2nd ther is NO WAY to get any information about the single cell or column, BUT you can store the needet Information in a derived class.

```
using System;
using Gtk;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestWinForms
{
    /// <summary>
    /// New cell renterer text. derived from Gtk.CellRendererText
    /// this was neccessary to host the column Index and a Name
    /// ( in this sample  the Attribute name, you can also define 
    ///   an oibject a dataRow or a XElement ... to use it directly.)
    /// </summary>
    public class NewCellRentererText : CellRendererText
    {
        public int ColumnIndex{ get; set;}
        public string XmlAttributeName{ get; set;}
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Main class.
    /// </summary>
    public class MainClass
    {
        /// <summary>Loaded XElement to show, edit and store </summary>
        private XElement MainXMLElement ;
        /// <summary>TreeStore used in several methodes</summary>
        private Gtk.TreeStore musicListStore;
        /// <summary>
        /// The editing queue.to find the correct Row that have been edited this is neccessary
        /// because the c# Integration of Gtk2 seems to be not thread safe
        /// </summary>
        private Queue<object> EditingQueue = new Queue<object>();

        /// <summary>
        /// The X element indexer.
        /// host for all editable XElements in the Tree
        /// using UserData results in an horrible Mix from managed and unmanaged code
        /// this way is clean safe.
        /// 
        /// An other solution will be to store the datareferences in an additional
        /// Property of NewCellRentererText 
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public Dictionary<TreeIter,XElement> XElementIndexer = new Dictionary<TreeIter, XElement> ();

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the dynamic tree filter reg ex.
        /// for filtering , this was only experimental, but it works fine. 
        /// So if it is needed ....
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The dynamic tree filter reg ex.</value>
        public System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex DynamicTreeFilterRegEx { get; set;} 
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the dynamic tree filter column.
        /// for filtering , this was only experimental, but it works fine. 
        /// So if it is needed ....
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The dynamic tree filter column.</value>
        public Int32 DynamicTreeFilterColumn { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The entry point of the program, where the program control starts and ends.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">The command-line arguments.</param>
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Gtk.Application.Init ();
            new MainClass ();
            Gtk.Application.Run ();

        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the window destroyed_callback event.
        /// safe my work :-)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="o">O.</param>
        /// <param name="args">Arguments.</param>
        public void On_WindowDestroyed_callback(object o, EventArgs args)
        {
            MainXMLElement.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine("Properties","ProcessOut.xml"));
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the editing canceled_callback event.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="o">O.</param>
        /// <param name="args">Arguments.</param>
        public void On_EditingCanceled_callback(object o, EventArgs args)
        {
            EditingQueue.Dequeue();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the editing started_callback event.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="o">O.</param>
        /// <param name="args">Arguments.</param>
        public void On_EditingStarted_callback(object o, EditingStartedArgs args)
        {
            EditingQueue.Enqueue (o);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the edited_callback event.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="o">O.</param>
        /// <param name="args">Arguments.</param>
        public void On_Edited_callback(object o, EditedArgs args)
        {
            object quedObject = EditingQueue.Dequeue ();
            NewCellRentererText ncrt = quedObject as NewCellRentererText;
            if (null == ncrt)
                return;

            TreeIter iter;
            TreePath path = new TreePath (args.Path);
            if (!musicListStore.GetIter (out iter, path))
                return;

            XElement dummy = XElementIndexer [iter];  
            if (dummy.Attribute (ncrt.XmlAttributeName) != null)
                dummy.SetAttributeValue (ncrt.XmlAttributeName, args.NewText);
            else
                foreach (string attrKvp in args.NewText.Split(";".ToCharArray())) {
                    String[] attribute = attrKvp.Split (":".ToCharArray ());
                    if (attribute.Length > 1) // && dummy.Attribute (attribute [0].Trim ()) != null)
                        dummy.SetAttributeValue (attribute [0].Trim (), attribute [1].Trim ());
                }
            musicListStore.SetValue (iter, ncrt.ColumnIndex, args.NewText);
            ((NewCellRentererText)o).Text = args.NewText;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the new column.
        /// set/reset the editable property
        /// ans set name and Column Index in a new instance
        /// of the new derived CellRendererText class 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The new column.</returns>
        /// <param name="index">Index.</param>
        /// <param name="name">Name.</param>
        /// <param name="editable">If set to <c>true</c> editable.</param>
        private Gtk.TreeViewColumn CreateNewColumn(int index, string name, bool editable)
        {
            NewCellRentererText renderer = new NewCellRentererText ();
            renderer.ColumnIndex =index ;
            renderer.XmlAttributeName=name;
            renderer.Editable = editable;
            if (editable) {
                renderer.Edited += On_Edited_callback;
                renderer.EditingStarted += On_EditingStarted_callback;
                renderer.EditingCanceled += On_EditingCanceled_callback;
            }
            Gtk.TreeViewColumn ret = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn (renderer.XmlAttributeName, renderer);
            ret.AddAttribute (ret.CellRenderers [0], "text", index);
            return ret;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="TestWinForms.MainClass"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainClass ()
        {
            // using Styles ( OPTIONAL EXPERIMENTAL BUT WORKING ) 
            Gtk.Rc.Parse (System.IO.Path.Combine("Properties","ProcessOut.xml"));

            // Normal stuff to create a tree view
            Gtk.Window window = new Gtk.Window ("TreeView Example");
            window.SetSizeRequest (800, 600);
            window.Destroyed += On_WindowDestroyed_callback;

            Gtk.TreeView tree = new Gtk.TreeView ();
            window.Add (tree);

            // one Part of the Solution to host column index
            tree.AppendColumn (CreateNewColumn(0, "name", false));
            tree.AppendColumn (CreateNewColumn(1, "id", false));
            tree.AppendColumn (CreateNewColumn(2, "type", true));
            tree.AppendColumn (CreateNewColumn(3, "class", true));
            tree.AppendColumn (CreateNewColumn(4, "parameter", true));
            tree.AppendColumn (CreateNewColumn(5, "others", true));
            Type[] TypeList = Enumerable.Repeat (typeof(string), tree.Columns.Length).ToArray();
                musicListStore = new Gtk.TreeStore (TypeList);

            // some XML stuff to make something usefull
            MainXMLElement = XElement.Load ("Properties/Process.xml",LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
            XElement y = MainXMLElement.Element ("processes");
            XAttribute title = y.Attribute ("name");
            TreeIter iter =  musicListStore.AppendValues(title == null ? y.Name.ToString() : title.Value);
            XElementIndexer.Add (iter, y);

            walkThroughXml (y, musicListStore, iter);

            // using row filter  ( OPTIONAL EXPERIMENTAL BUT WORKING ) 
            Gtk.TreeModelFilter filter = new Gtk.TreeModelFilter (musicListStore, null);
            filter.VisibleFunc = new Gtk.TreeModelFilterVisibleFunc (FilterTree);

            tree.Model = filter;

            // Now let us see
            window.ShowAll ();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Walks the through xml.
        /// recursive TreView filling based on an XML Element
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="xe">Xe.</param>
        /// <param name="ts">Ts.</param>
        /// <param name="ti">Ti.</param>
        public void walkThroughXml(XElement xe, Gtk.TreeStore ts, Gtk.TreeIter ti )
        {
            if (!xe.HasElements)
                return;
            IEnumerable<XElement> elements = xe.Elements ();
            foreach ( XElement element in elements )
            {
                // this part could be more generic, but it works for my requirements
                String Xid = "";
                String Xtype = "";
                String Xclass = "";
                String Xparameter = "";

                System.Text.StringBuilder dataExpression = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                XAttribute title = element.Attribute ("name");
                foreach (XAttribute data in element.Attributes()) {
                    switch (data.Name.ToString ()) {
                    case "name":
                        break;
                    case "id":
                        Xid = data.Value;
                        break;
                    case "type":
                        Xtype = data.Value;
                        break;
                    case "class":
                        Xclass = data.Value;
                        break;
                    case "parameter":
                        Xparameter = data.Value;
                        break;
                    default:
                        dataExpression.AppendFormat ("{0}: {1} ; ", data.Name.ToString (), data.Value);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                TreeIter iter = (TreeIter)ts.AppendValues (ti, title == null ? element.Name.ToString () : title.Value, Xid,Xtype,Xclass,Xparameter, dataExpression.ToString ());
                walkThroughXml (element, ts, iter);
                XElementIndexer.Add (iter,element);
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Filters the tree.       
        ///
        /// for filtering , this was only experimental, but it works fine. 
        /// So if it is needed ....
        ///
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns><c>true</c>, if tree was filtered, <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
        /// <param name="model">Model.</param>
        /// <param name="iter">Iter.</param>
        private bool FilterTree (Gtk.TreeModel model, Gtk.TreeIter iter)
        {
            if (DynamicTreeFilterRegEx == null)
                return true;
            string searchName = model.GetValue (iter, DynamicTreeFilterColumn).ToString ();
            return DynamicTreeFilterRegEx.IsMatch (searchName);
        }

    }
}
```

For testin here the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<document>
    <enums>
    </enums>
    <processes>
        <process name="main" id="p1" positionmeasurement="milliseconds" speed="4100" processlength="10000" maxitems="255" mingap="5">
            <actuators>
                <actuator name="actuator1" id="p1pa1" type="sensor" class="" parameter="" position="100" window="220" />
                <actuator name="actuator2" id="p1pa2" type="sensor" class="" parameter=""  position="1050" window="220" />
                <actuator name="actuator3" id="p1pa3" type="receiver" class="" parameter=""  position="9100" window="220" />
            </actuators>
            <processsteps>
                <processstep name="step1" id="p1ps0" type="runningstate" class="" parameter="" order="1" retriggerable="true" />                
                <processstep name="step1" id="p1ps1" type="sync" class="" parameter="" order="2" retriggerable="false" />
                <processstep name="step2" id="p1ps2" type="async" class="" parameter="" order="3" retriggerable="true" />
                <processstep name="step3" id="p1ps3" type="timed" position="25000" window="1200" class="" parameter="" order="4" retriggerable="false" />
            </processsteps>
            <triggers>
                <trigger name="trigger1" id="p1pt1" sourceid="p1pa2" sourcestate="start" targetid="p1ps2" triggertype="start" />
                <trigger name="trigger2" id="p1pt2" sourceid="p1pa2" sourcestate="error" targetid="p1ps2" triggertype="stop" />
                <trigger name="trigger3" id="p1pt3" sourceid="p1pa3" sourcestate="end" targetid="p1ps3" triggertype="start" />
            </triggers>
            <assertations>
                <assertation name="assertation1" id="p1pas1" type="itemstate" rule="text" class="" parameter="" />
                <assertation name="assertation2" id="p1pas2" type="itemstate" rule="text" class="" parameter="" />
                <assertation name="assertation3" id="p1pas3" type="itemstate" rule="text" class="" parameter="" />
            </assertations>
            <exceptions>
                <exception name="exception1" id="p1pex1" retriggerable="false">
                    <conditions logic="and">
                        <condition name="contition1" id="p1pex1c1" class="" paramter="" type="PLC" message="2001" /> 
                        <condition name="contition2" id="p1pex1c2" class="" paramter="" type="PLC" message="2005" /> 
                    </conditions>
                    <actions>
                        <action name="action1" id="p1pex1pac1" class="" parameter="" actiontype="stopfeeder" type="asynchron" order="1" />
                        <action name="action1" id="p1pex1pac1" class="" parameter="" actiontype="flushallitem" type="synchron" timeout="5000" order="2" />
                        <action name="action2" id="p1pex1pac2" class="" parameter="" actiontype="rundown" type="synchron" timeout="5000" order="3" />
                    </actions>
                </exception>
            </exceptions>
        </process>
        <process name="sub" id="p2">
        </process>
        <process name="sub2" id="p3">
            <actuators>
                <actuator name="actuator1" id="p3pa1" type="sensor" class="" parameter="" />
                <actuator name="actuator2" id="p3pa2" type="sensor" class="" parameter="" />
                <actuator name="actuator3" id="p3pa3" type="receiver" class="" parameter="" />
            </actuators>
            <processsteps>
                <processstep name="step1" id="p3ps0" type="runningstate" class="" parameter="" />               
                <processstep name="step1" id="p3ps1" type="sync" class="" parameter="" />
                <processstep name="step2" id="p3ps2" type="async" class="" parameter="" />
                <processstep name="step3" id="p3ps3" type="timed" processtime="25000" window="1200" class="" parameter="" />
            </processsteps>
            <triggers>
                <trigger name="trigger1" id="p3pt1" sourceid="p3pa2" sourcestate="start" targetid="p3ps2" triggertype="start" />
                <trigger name="trigger2" id="p3pt2" sourceid="p3pa2" sourcestate="error" targetid="p3ps2" triggertype="stop" />
                <trigger name="trigger3" id="p3pt3" sourceid="p3pa3" sourcestate="end" targetid="p3ps3" triggertype="start" />
            </triggers>
            <assertations>
                <assertation name="assertation1" id="p3pas1" type="itemstate" rule="text" class="" parameter="" />
                <assertation name="assertation2" id="p3pas2" type="itemstate" rule="text" class="" parameter="" />
                <assertation name="assertation3" id="p3pas3" type="itemstate" rule="text" class="" parameter="" />
            </assertations>
        </process>
    </processes>

</document>
```

save this in the properties Folder and check to copy